# How do you take commas out of integers in HeidiSQL?

Tags: heidisql

In HeidiSQL, integers display with commas; I'd like numbers to display with no commas. Old posts on this say to go to Tools > Preferences > Text Formatting > "Local Number Format", but in the newest version of HeidiSQL (12.5.0.6677) there is no "Text Formatting" area under preferences, or any obvious way to get rid of those commas.

Comment: Okay, looks like you have to go Tools > Preferences > Grid Formatting and uncheck "local number format". Except, now I have a row of floats that I'd like always to display in x.xx format. No obvious way to do that.

Comment: You want to display only 2 decimals of these floats, or what do you achieve? If so, you can change the data type of the columns to `DECIMAL(10,2)`.